# anacron not executing scheduled jobs

Tags: cron, scheduled-job

I am trying to execute cron.php for all Civicrm jobs through the Anacron tab on the cpanel of Gandi, but I keep getting "execute_all_jobs: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../civicrm.config.php"
I have tried setting permissions on bin and cron.php to 777, and also with and without username/password/site key.
Additionally, I get a "page not found" if I try to use a URL call

Any suggestions? Please?

Comment: What command are you using to run cron? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#commands

Comment: I am using the URL method, through the GANDI control panel Anacron tab. I have 2 php crons set up for process_mailing and fetch_bounces, and one for execute_all_jobs, but all of them give me a "input file not found" result with or without username/password/site key.

Comment: UPDATE: I added a query string, but now it said Can't open file.
I looked at civcrm-settings.php and the user Framework ResourceURL doesn't contain htdocs in the path, but global $civicrm does (which is the absolute path I am using for cron - with htdocs). When I tried to add htdocs to the user Framework Resource URL, CivicCRM did not display correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit the original question to show the exact command you are using (except passwords)? And are you using wget or curl or something else?

Comment: this is the command suggested by GANDI (with the name, pass and key redacted:
@hourly 0 execute_all_jobs php -f /srv/data/web/vhosts/hungeractionnys.org/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin$ php /srv/data/web/vhosts/hungeractionnys.org/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?&name=[name]&pass=[pass]&key=[key]

Comment: sorry, it is this now, with the query:
@hourly 0 execute_all_jobs php -f /srv/data/web/vhosts/hungeractionnys.org/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin$ php /srv/data/web/vhosts/hungeractionnys.org/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php '&name=[name]&pass=[pass]&key=[key]'

Comment: Ok I see that's not the right command. If you want to use the URL method, then the command is not `php`, it is `curl` or `wget` as described at docs I linked above.

Comment: But the GANDI DOCS say:

You can also execute scripts written in PHP. To do this, you will need to use the php command, along with the -f option, and the path to the file.

Your files will still be located at the same location (/srv/data/web/vhosts), followed by the directory of the VHOST and the path to the file within the code of your application.

In the following example, we execute a file called cron.php daily at the root of www.example.com.

@daily 0 my_php_script php -f /srv/data/web/vhosts/www.example.com/cron.php

so, does this need to be different for CiviCRM crons???

Comment: I see the confusion but the url method works by simulating a web browser visiting a url so it's not running a command line php script. You need to use curl or similar to simulate the web browser, not php.

Comment: i don't understand how to use curl. there is no curl directory in /bin, so do i need to create one? and, if so, what file do i create to put in there?

Comment: Also, is there possibly an issue with the htdocs  being in the Framework Resource path, but not $global civicrm...as i mentioned above